# FFMPEG with javaCV can't open stream

Tags: ffmpeg

I having a strange behavior when testing to get the video Stream of a Mobotix camera, I'm using javaCV 0.11.
When I set a timeout I can't open the stream, the stream only open if I don't set the timeout parameter.

I verified this behavior with javaCV 0.11 and Java CV 0.11 in version 0.9 and 0.8 it works with the timeout.

Probably an error of the lib JavaCV or the way I'm using it :P

My question for the ffmpeg experts is the following:

When I'm calling:

```
avformat_open_input
```

the function returns -138

I called the function av_strerror fir this error code and the function was returned "Error number -138 occurred".

A description not very useful, can someone tell me what this error means?

Comment: Post some code when you're opening the file, please

Comment: I found my problem I was setting the timeout parameter in seconds, in newer ffmpeg versions is to be set in microseconds, Thanks for the help.
http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#http
timeout
Set timeout in microseconds of socket I/O operations used by the underlying low level operation. By default it is set to -1, which means that the timeout is not specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error -138 flags a timeout.

From **errno.h**:

```
#define ETIMEDOUT       138
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to that file?

Comment: Sure... one of the places is in your Visual Studio installation path, in my case "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\errno.h"